# how to test bad network connection with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, rspec2, vcr

I'd like to test for connection errors to an external api. What is the best way to go about and do this?

in my controller i have

```
begin
 result = connect.to_api
rescue Error::TooManyRequests => e
 flash = e
end
```

I'd like to test that the error gets displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my test to pass with

`Connect.should_receive(:to_api).and_raise(Error::TooManyRequests)`

Answer (score 1):

Mock your `connect` object so that whatever method it calls raises the errors you'd expect to get when the network is done.  Then test that the error gets set where you expect it to.  Without knowing that `connect.to.api` really is, it's kind of hard to say what you should mock and what you should raise...

Comment: Thanks. connect.to.api in this case is Twitter.search(params[:q]) which may raise Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests